# Multiple BOOLEANS or one BIGINT for storing MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, integer, boolean

I have these orderLines that can be of type quotation or booking. On the orderLine level in the database, I want to keep track what the current type is of a line. I could create 2 booleans `isQuotation` and `isBooking` that can be either true or false, or I could create a `type` field where `0 = quotation` etc. Based on best practices, what's the best way to do this?

Comment: Can your entry be both quotation and booking (or some potentially additional states you invent in the future) at the same time? (Or, in other words, would isQuotation = 1 and isBooking = 1 make sense, or is always exactly one state true?)

Comment: @Solarflare No, it can be only one state at the same time, it is however possible the more states will be added (which could bloat the db with bools)

Answer (score 1):

```
type ENUM('quotation', 'booking') NOT NULL
```

allows 2 choices takes one byte.  It can be tested via things like `type = 'booking'`.  I usually prefer to add a third option rather than allowing `NULL`:

```
type ENUM('unknown', 'quotation', 'booking') NOT NULL
```

For up to 256 options, it still takes 1 byte.

A `BIGINT` takes 8 bytes; overkill.

```
type SET('quotation', 'booking') NOT NULL
```

takes 1 byte and allows 4 choices -- including both and neither.

There is probably no need for `NULL`; simply use the empty set.  Set is limited to 64 independent options, which would take 8 bytes.

Some people disapprove of using `ENUM`, so I will mention `TINYINT UNSIGNED` as a 1-byte alternative with a limit of 256 choices.  You could, then, have another table that maps the numbers to human-friendly strings.